# Use IQueryable.Count<T> with an IEnumerable<T> parameter

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

imagine a class, let's say for pagination which could be used with an `IList<T>` or an `IQueryable<T>`.

That class would have an `int TotalItems` property, which would (not that surprising) get / set the count of the queryable or enumerable parameter.

If I use `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter,

```
//simplified
public Pagination(IEnumerable<T> query)
    {
        TotalItems = query.Count();
    }
```

the `Count()` method will be (**if I'm not wrong, that's the point**) `Enumerable.Count()`. So even if query is an `IQueryable<T>` (which inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`), it will be enumerated (which is obviously not desired with a "db query").

So is there a way to use `Queryable.Count()` method when my `IEnumerable<T>` is in fact an `IQueryable<T>`, or do I have to change my design, having, for example in this case, 2 ctor

```
//simplified
public Pagination(IEnumerable<T> query)
    {
         TotalItems = query.Count();
    }
public Pagination(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
         TotalItems = query.Count();
    }
```

**EDIT**
I do understand that `IQueryable<T>` inheriting from `IEnumerable<T>` has nothing to do with the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` have extension methods with same name, and that it's nice to have same names for extension method, which "look like they do the same", but I think it still sometimes confusing...

**Generic question for curiosity**

Are they other examples, in framework, with the same "architecture" : inheritance  + common names for extension methods ?

Comment: why not just accept an `int` and let them count a sequence/query if that's where the count comes from?

Comment: @AakashM well, this question comes after a real try, and a look at MiniProfiler results : I may have done a bad interpretation, in that case, I'll smash my head on a wall ;)

Comment: @Servy as pointed, this is a simplified case, I might want to use the `query` parameter for other purpose in my class, and call other "shared" queryable or Enumerable extension methods, which would have the same problem (if the problem exists).

Comment: Hi, if i am not wrong...if IEnumerable<T> is the parameter and you pass it IQueryable<T>, then query.Count() will call the method Count defined with IQueryable ( default polymorphism behavior )??

Comment: @DnshPly9 that's where the thing is "confusing". Count() is not a method of `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, it's, or to be correct "they are" extension methods... So the extension methods have just the same name, but not related at all with polymorphism mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have two constructor overloads, as you showed in the question.  This makes it up to the caller whether they want the `IQueryable` methods to be used, or the `IEnumerable` methods to be used.

If someone were to do:

```
Pagination pager = new Pagination(query.AsEnumerable());
```

Then they clearly want the object to be processed as an `IEnumearble`, not an `IQueryable`.  Perhaps they know that `Skip` and `Take` aren't implemented by their query provider and so the pagination will fail, and it needs to be evaluated as Linq-to-objects.

By having the two overloads you make it an informed decision by the user of your class whether they're dealing with an in memory sequence or a query, rather than trying to figure it out on your own.

Comment: +1, good example with Skip/Take that might be not supported by the query provider.

Comment: +1 also, good example of not implemented extension methods on different providers. Soon accepted, just a question : don't you think that I could then have the ctor with IEnumerable<T> parameter replaced by an IList<T> parameter : knowing that Count() will enumerate anyway, this would make things clearer, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do:

```
TotalItems = enumerable.AsQueryable().Count();
```

This would directly use the query-provider's `Count` implementation for a native queryable, or fallback to LINQ to Objects (with some overhead for using an `EnumerableQuery`) otherwise.

Another solution  (potentially more efficient):

```
var queryable = enumerable as IQueryable<T>;
TotalItems = queryable != null ? queryable.Count() : enumerable.Count();
```

However, note that if your queryable implements `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` efficiently (as is the case with some query providers), even your existing solution would potentially work well because of optimizations within LINQ (it uses the `Count` property from those interfaces where possible). For your `IList<T>`, it will always use this optimization since it implements `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: This could cause problems though.  If someone has an `IQueryable` and they call `AsEnumerable` on it it means that they *want* it to be resolved as LINQ-to-objects, and not perform subsequent queries against the query provider.

Comment: @Servy well, would it really be performed (again) against the query provider, as it will have been enumerated with `AsEnumerable()` ? Must admit I'm not that clear on what's happen with an `IQueryable<T>().AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()`...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus No, `AsEnumerable` doesn't enumerate anything, it effectively doesn't do anything more than cast the object to `IEnumerable`.  The full definition is: `public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {return source;}`

Comment: @Servy: I don't understand your point. The OP *specifically* wants the query-provider's Count() implementation for native queryables.

Comment: @Ani But at the end of the day it should be up to the caller which is used, he just wants it to use the `Queryable` method *if they knowingly passed in an `IQueryable`, but not if they didn't.